# Conditionally embedding a non-product element in a Shopify collection grid

Tags: shopify

This seems like an easy one, but after researching and banging around for a couple of hours I still can't figure it out. My goal is to insert a non-product HTML block in the Shopify collection grid, like the "Enjoy Free Ground Shipping" block in row 1, col 3 here:

http://www.katespade.com/designer-handbags/handbags,default,sc.html

My collection grid is set to 3 columns by 4 rows per page, and I'm looking to replace the block at row 2, column 1 for all collection pages with 3 or more products.

The Liquid loop I need to modify is:

```
    <ul class="product-grid clearfix">
    {% for product in collection.products %}
      <li{% cycle '', '', ' class="last-in-row"' %}>
        {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Hello, handwovensole!  Did the answer I posted end up working out for you? If not, let me know and I'll give it another shot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)

First, let me pseudocode this to make sure we're on the same page, and that I've got the logic right.

```
for each product in collection
{
    is this the 4th iteration of the loop?
    (in other words, is it the first item in the second row)
    {
        Add an <li> for the custom non-product block.
    }

    Add an <li> for the standard product block
}
```

If that logic fits what you're looking for, here's the real thing in Liquid.

```
<ul class="product-grid clearfix">

{% for product in collection.products %}

    {% if forloop.index == 4 %}
        <li{% cycle '', '', ' class="last-in-row"' %}>
            {% include 'your-custom-block-element' %}
        </li>
    {% endif %}

    <li{% cycle '', '', ' class="last-in-row"' %}>
        {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
    </li>

{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

You may have noticed that Shopify deals with 1-based indices by default.  That's why we're looking for `forloop.index == 4`.  In almost every other language we'd be dealing with a zero-based index and checking if `forloop.index == 3`.

If this convention bugs you, you can always use `forloop.index0` to check for the loop's index with a base of zero instead.  ;-)

Please let me know if this does the trick for you.  Good luck!